# Docker Spring Boot MVC app failing when scaled to multiple instances

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a `Java 11`, `Spring Boot 2.7.4` application using `Spring MVC` and `Spring Security` to allow users to upload and search for documents in a repository. The application is deployed as a `Docker` container to `AWS EC2` instances and is accessed via a load balancer.

The application works fine when deployed as a single instance. However, when I attempt to scale it to 2 replicas, I see intermittent errors like this:

```
This site can’t be reached. The webpage at http://load-balancer:port/content/login might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE
```

I have extended `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and overridden configure as shown below: -

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        String[] antMatchers = antMatcherPatterns.split(ANT_MATCHERS_DELIMITER);

        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(antMatchers)
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/content/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/content/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/content/logout")
                .permitAll();
    }
```

A `Spring Controller` is implemented to handle user requests. An edited version is pasted below: -

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/content")
public class ContentLandingController { 

    @GetMapping("/documents/{app}")
    public ModelAndView getDocumentsPage(@PathVariable("app") String app, HttpServletRequest req, Principal principal) {
        //Prepare the view
        ModelAndView modelAndView = modelAndViewHelper.getSearchPageModelAndView(application, metadataListWrapper, principal);
        return modelAndView;
    }

}
```

The application listens on a fixed port, which is hard coded in the `Docker` `stack.yml` file. Could this be the issue? And if so, how should this be addressed? I did wonder if having multiple instances listening on the same port could be the root cause. However, the logs show that all instances start normally.

I would be extremely grateful for any suggestions and or advice on this issue. Many thanks for reading my post.

Comment: So, where did you store the shared sessiom-related data? Could all instances access those data accordingly? Just remember your traffic could be loadbalanced to any instance. session data should be accessible at any instance if you replicated your pod to more than one.

Comment: @GeminiKeith Many thanks for the reply. You could well be right here. I am not doing anything to explicitly share session data. I was hoping all that would be handled by the Spring framework automatically as this is a common requirement - but that's a lot to ask I guess! Would you be able to share any reference / links / patterns on how session data can be shared across instances as I am new to this? I would be most grateful for any assistance :)

Comment: Suppose you are using spring session to manage sessions, you can check `Spring Session`  reference https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/reference/guides/boot-redis.html . However, I suggest you post your operation flow step by step and show us which step failed and for what. That will be useful to figure out what the real issue might be.

Comment: @GeminiKeith Many thanks again Keith. I currently have no explicit session management implemented. I am going to implement Spring Session with redis as a start point and see how it behaves once I've done that. Will come back to let you know how I get on. Appreciate the support! :)

Comment: Never mind. More steps and errors would be useful. You can just post more details if you encounter more problems.